# Current method of sending POST request on Android applications

Tags: android, http, post, http-post

I'm looking for an updated way to send POST requests from my Android app to a web server and get a response.

Most tutorials and codes I see use a class called `HttpPost` from the `org.apache.http.client.methods` package.

I'm using Android Studio and the SDK is updated and the documentation as well. It says `HttpPost` is deprecated. In fact most of these tutorials are 2, 3, and even 5 years old. I remember having done it a few years ago and I believe I used `HttpPost`, but since Android is in constant development things must have changed.

What is the current way to send a HTTP POST request and get a response from the server?

Comment: HttpUrlConnection. You will find hundreds of examples on this site. Every day again there are. I can only advice to use it and to not loose yourself in libraries as Volley e.o. if you also want to understand the http process.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use one of the popular libraries that handle a lot of these interactions for you. I personally use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) but [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) is also quite popular.

The advantage of using libraries like this include:

- Great open source community that collectively improves, optimizes, and removes bugs from the code
- You don't reinvent the wheel improving your own code quality
- Easy to read and even easier to test

In short, I would advocate against using the native Apache provided network adapters and try leverage one of the libraries I mentioned above as there is no need to reinvent the wheel.